# Перекодировка QuickTime stream в поток, другого формата.

Tags: flash, видео, iphone

Имеется камера, которая отдает поток в формате `video/quicktime`, `ffmpeg` его не читает.
Есть ли возможность его перекодировать, чтобы можно было воспроизвести на сайте с помощью `flash`?

Comment: А что, mplayer/mencoder его не читает? Я-то думал, что он всё ест.

Comment: А разве mencoder может кодировать потоковое видео?

Comment: Судя по описанию -- да.

Answer (score 1):

Для воспроизведения на flash нужно кодировать в формат FLV/F4v. 
Например этим занимается Adobe Media Encoder.